# Append to existing text - Exporting to Excel

Tags: custom-list, excel, export, append-changes

I have been looking online and can't really seem to find any clear information relating to this so thought I would pick all of your brains.

I have a custom list with a multiple lines of text column which has append to existing text enabled. Now this itself isn't causing any issues and everything in the list works as expected however the issue seems to be when exporting the list to excel. This column just shows as blank in the spreadsheet and I suppose my question is can I do anything to pull this information through so our reporting team can see them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting to excel will only send the current version of all the items to excel. Having appending text in a multiple line of text field only works when version history is on. Therefore if someone wrote something in the multiple line of text and it is not in the current version you wont see it in your excel export.

I found this post useful as you will need to do some more steps to extract the version history with your export.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561661/sharepoint-list-version-history-export-to-excel

Other than that you can just view it in the browser and tell people to open the items or look at the version history to find out when different entries were made.